# Carpentry can't find wood

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have two wood stockpiles, one directly connected to my carpentry workshop; however, when I go to build beds, I get (bed canceled, need logs.) I am confused as there is a wood stockpile two spaces to the right

Comment: Are the logs forbidden or dump tagged ? Is your stockpile restricted by some rules ? Try to remove and create the stockpile again

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that the workshop can not be the exact same size as the mine. It needs at least one free space on all neighboring squares

Comment: That's not true. All workshops have impassable tiles and there needs to be a valid path from the logs to the center tile of the workshop. Mining a free space on every neighboring square would certainly guarantee there is always a path to the central tile of the workshop, but it is absolutely not necessary.